# Finding the array with the smallest Nth value in a JavaScript 2D Array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a 2-D JavaScript array of varying length and I want to have retrieved the array with the smallest value in index N. Let us say N = 9. If my 2-D array was:

> [ [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11] , [11,10,9,8,7,6,5,4,3,2,100,1] ]

I'd want to have returned:

> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11]

Any tips on how to go about this?

Thanks.

Comment: Iterate and compare?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var result = TwoDArray[0];
for(var i = 1; i < TwoDArray.length; i++){
  if(TwoDArray[i][N] !== undefined && TwoDArray[i][N] < result[N]) result = TwoDArray[i];
}

return result;
```

This sets the result as the first value, and compares it against the rest of the arrays in TwoDArray.